How to get Siri to listen to audio input on MacOS
Sequoia 15.1, 2023 M2 mini
I would like Siri to respond to my spoken voice (not typing).
When I have voice control activated, I can say "open siri" and Siri opens for typing input. The words I speak show up and Siri responds to my request when I press enter. If I click on the microphone icon to Talk to Siri, Siri does not respond to the words I speak. When I do not have voice control activated, I manually click on the Siri taskbar icon and it comes up in Talk to Siri mode. Siri does not respond to the words I speak.

Sound input is set to this external microphone (below), which works great for voice control. It does not work for Talk to Siri.

Is there a specific device setting for audio input for Talk to Siri? What configuration am I missing to make this work?

How exactly are you connecting your external mic?  From information gleaned from the screen-shot I assume you're using the AudioTechnica 2020 mic. It is a wired (XLR) mic, so you are using an interface of some sort, such as a Scarlet branded interface. Please specify which interface is in use. Also - I see below (in cut-off text) the AT2020 what might be an attached webcam. What happens if you disconnect the web-cam. Is the interface going through a hub instead of direct?

I don't understand the question regarding the interface - it's just a usb-A device, nothing special other than yes, it's going through a USB hub, not direct. The hub does also have an attached webcam. If removing the webcam makes it work I am just not going to use this "feature" because I am not going to disconnect it every time I want to talk to Siri.

Is the mic indeed an Audio Technica 2020? Specs show it is a XLR (3-pin) wired mic.

It's an AT 2020 USB.

Scroll down to the very end to take look at the macOS section on this page at AudioTechnica. I was going to recommend that you check out Utilities > Audio MIDI Setup to make adjustments to various parameters in an attempt to see the mic. The AT page may have what you're looking for.
